# Derivative of a vector divided by its norm w.r.t a parameter

Tags: calculus, derivatives, vectors, normed-spaces

Let say that we have the vector $V(\theta)=[-2\theta \hspace{0.2cm} \theta^2 \hspace{0.2cm} \theta^3]^T$, and the elements of $V$ are differentiable functions of $\theta$ and The norm of the vector $V$ equal to $\|V(\theta)\| = \sqrt{(-2\theta)^2 + (\theta^2)^2 + (\theta^3)^2}$.

Is there a direct expression of the derivative of the following formula w.r.t the parameter $\theta$:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left (\frac{V(\theta)}{\|V(\theta)\|} \right)$$

Comment: Yes, you merely have to take the ordinary derivative of each component, each being a function of the single variable $\theta$.  So$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \left (\frac{V(\theta)}{\|V(\theta)\|} \right)=\frac{d}{d \theta} \left (\frac{V(\theta)}{\|V(\theta)\|} \right)$.

Comment: In fact I have tried that procedure by using a simple example with $V=[1\, \theta]^T$ and I also used the product rule $\frac{V'(\theta) \|V(\theta)\|-V(\theta)\|V(\theta)\|'}{\|V(\theta)\|^2} $ and the result is the same. So Seems like product rule works in this case as well, the question : is the product rule can be applicable for any vector $V(\theta)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $\,\lambda=\|v\|\,\,$ denote the length of the vector, and find its differential 
$$\eqalign{
  \lambda^2 &= v^Tv \cr
  2\lambda\,d\lambda &= 2v^Tdv \implies d\lambda=\frac{v^Tdv}{\lambda} \cr
}$$
Express the unit vector in terms of $\lambda$, then find its differential and derivative
$$\eqalign{
 s &= \frac{v}{\lambda} \cr\cr
ds &= \frac{\lambda\,dv-v\,d\lambda}{\lambda^2} \cr
   &= \frac{1}{\lambda}(dv-ss^Tdv) \cr
   &= \frac{1}{\lambda}(I-ss^T)\,dv \cr\cr
\frac{ds}{d\theta} &= \Big(\frac{I-ss^T}{\lambda}\Big)\,\frac{dv}{d\theta} \cr
}$$

Comment: I am curious about the second order derivative? How can I calculate it?