# Differential of the map $N(p) = (Bp+ b)/|Bp+b|$

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

My question is simple, I just want to compute the differential of the map
$$
N(p) = \frac{Bp + b}{|Bp + b|}
$$
where $B$ is a non-null symmetric matrix of order three, $b \in \Bbb{R}^3$ and $p \in S$ where $S$ is the following surface (a quadric):
$$
S = \{p \in \Bbb{R}^3 \ | \ \langle Bp, p \rangle +  2\langle b, p \rangle + c = 0\},
$$
with $c \in \Bbb{R}^3$.

The context is the following: the question asks to show that $N(p)$ is a Gauss map on $S$ and to compute the corresponding second fundamental form. I am stuck in this second part. The solution is
$$
\sigma_p = - \frac{1}{|Bp + b|} \langle Bv, v \rangle \quad p \in S, v \in T_pS
$$

EDIT:

Following the hint by Jean Marie:

The jacobian matrix of $q \mapsto \frac{q}{|q|}$ is given by
$$1/|q|^3
\begin{bmatrix}
q_2^2+q_3^2 & - q_1q_2 & - q_1q_3 \\
    &  q_1^2 + q_3^2 & -q_2q_3 \\
    &              & q_1^2+q_2^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
Then, if $N = f \circ g$ we have $(dN)_p(v) = df(g(p)) dg(p) (v) = \frac{1}{|Bv+b|^3} * [matrix] * Bv$. Is this correct? If so, how do I arrive at 
$$
\sigma_p(v, v) = - \frac{1}{|Bp + b|}\langle Bv, v \rangle
$$
?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider your issue as the computation of the derivative of the composition of two functions : $p \mapsto q=Bp+b$ (which is plainly $B$) and $q \mapsto \frac{q}{|q|}$ (which has some problems in  $0$...)

Comment: The problem of $q$ being zero in the second function is solved b saying that the quadric is regular? What does "regular" mean?

Comment: "Regular" is opposite to "Singular", therefore means invertible (for the matrix), i.e., for quadrics, not a degenerate quadric such as a pair of planes ....

Comment: @JeanMarie please see the edit in my question

Comment: connected question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2135038

Comment: I agree for you non-diagonal elements  of your matrix, but the diagonal elements should be $q_2^2+q_3^2$, etc...

Comment: I apologize for my difficulty but I am still clueless on how to arrive at the desired result

Comment: The matrix can be written $(1/|q|)(I-VV^T)$ where $V^T=(q_1,q_2,q_3)/|q|$ (I.e. a projection matrix)

Comment: I realize that the last expression for the matrix can as well be found in the connected question I gave upwards.

Comment: Still another connected question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3587244

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed this with the help of Renan Lima.

We use the definition to compute the differential of $N$ at $p \in S$. Let $\alpha: (- \varepsilon, \varepsilon) \longrightarrow S$ be a curve such that $\alpha(0) = p$ and $\alpha'(0) = v$, for $v \in T_pS$. Then
$$
(dN)_p(v) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t = 0} N(\alpha(t)) = \frac{Bv}{|Bp + b|} + \frac{\langle Bv, Bp + b \rangle}{|Bp + b|}(Bp + b).
$$

Since we are interested only on the tangential component, that is $(dN)_p|_{T_{N(p)}\Bbb{S}^2}$, is suffices to take only the first term. This gives the expression we are seeking.

For more details about the computations, see [this link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1B75z0L4ArDN25r0I64tC_hMsSCe1NqER).